# Can I create temporary tables inside MySQL recurring events?

Tags: mysql, sql, temp-tables

MySQL documentation says that temporary tables are cleared after a session is closed? Does that mean if I create a temporary table inside a block of a recurring even, then this table is dropped automatically after I end my db connection? and this way if the recurring events runs over time it won't find the table?
What's the solution to this problem? I need to save some records of a query inside a recurring event.

Comment: " I need to save some records of a query inside a recurring event." - then don't use a temporary table!

Comment: @MitchWheat What do you suggest to use instead?

Comment: a permanent table, somewhat obviously.

Comment: I don't have access for any DDL queries :( @MitchWheat

Comment: Then I guess you're SOOL! Or get someone to add a th required table to your SCC and deploy it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct, in MySQL, temporary tables will only last as long as the session is alive. You cannot access a temp table outside of the session that created it: [Source](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-temporary-tables.htm)

There is no Global temp table in MySQL (as opposed to MS SQL Server)... but using a global temp table in MS SQL Server is not really a good practice anyways... if you need to persist the data, you need to use a permanent table.

Comment: I thought of that actually, but the problem is that I don't have access for any DDL queries :(

Comment: To clarify this concept in the context of the MySQL event scheduler, each invocation of a scheduled event is its own session with its own unique `CONNECTION_ID()`.  Even if an event runs so long that it is invoked again while still running, the two invocations can't see each other's temp tables.